# mac script command not found though the file is there

Tags: macos

This is the script that I have

```
#!/bin/sh

trap `rm -f tmp.$$; exit 1` 1 2 15

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    head -`expr $i \* 20000` u.data | tail -20000 > tmp.$$
    sort -t"    " -k 1,1n -k 2,2n tmp.$$ > u$i.test
    head -`expr \( $i - 1 \) \* 20000` u.data > tmp.$$
    tail -`expr \( 5 - $i \) \* 20000` u.data >> tmp.$$
    sort -t"    " -k 1,1n -k 2,2n tmp.$$ > u$i.base
done

allbut.pl ua 1 10 100000 u.data
sort -t"    " -k 1,1n -k 2,2n ua.base > tmp.$$
mv tmp.$$ ua.base
sort -t"    " -k 1,1n -k 2,2n ua.test > tmp.$$
mv tmp.$$ ua.test

allbut.pl ub 11 20 100000 u.data
sort -t"    " -k 1,1n -k 2,2n ub.base > tmp.$$
mv tmp.$$ ub.base
sort -t"    " -k 1,1n -k 2,2n ub.test > tmp.$$
mv tmp.$$ ub.test
```

when I run it, i see this error:

```
mku.sh: line 14: allbut.pl: command not found
mku.sh: line 20: allbut.pl: command not found
```

Though the **allbut.pl** file is there at the same directly with the script

**i don't know the correct tags for this question**

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for answering but i'm on vacation, will be back tomorrow and i'll check

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the lines with `allbut`:

```
allbut.pl ua 1 10 100000 u.data
```

to:

```
./allbut.pl ua 1 10 100000 u.data
```

Try also ensuring that that script is executable:

```
chmod +x allbut.pl
```